# Pure virtual function = unreferenced local variable warning

Tags: c++

**Conclusion for upcoming readers**

An abstract class inside a function is not a good idea (at least with VS2013 Update 3, it might be a bug). See **Edit 3** and Leon's answer for more detail.

**Original Post**

I've never got this warning and I have no idea what's happening. I set up my project to treat warnings as errors.

```
class BaseFoo
{
public:
    virtual ~BaseFoo() = default;

    virtual void doIt(const std::string& x, const uint8 y) = 0;
}; // class BaseFoo

class Foo : public BaseFoo
{
    void doIt(const std::string& x, const uint8 y) override
    {
    }
}; // class Foo

class Executer
{
public:
    void doIt(BaseFoo* f)
    {
        f->doIt("hello", 0);
        f->doIt("world", 1);
    }
}; // class Executer

Executer exec;
BaseFoo* f = new Foo();
exec.doIt(f);
delete f;
```

MSVC (VS2013 Update 3) says:

> warning C4101: 'BaseFoo::doIt' : unreferenced local variable

How can a pure virtual function be "unreferenced local **variable**"? I must be a potato or I found a compiler bug?

**Edit:**

If I put code into the `Foo::doIt` function (eg. an std::cout), nothing changes.

If I change `BaseFoo::doIt` to non-pure just a "simple" virtual function, which does nothing, the warning disappears.

**Edit 2: Compilable single file**

So I've "copy-pasted" the code into a compilable main function (I know, argv, argc, meh... :)). I've also copied the project settings:

- Warning Level3: /W3
- Treat warnings as errors: Yes /WX
- Optimization: Disabled /Od
- Minimal rebuild: Enabled /Gm
- RTTI: No /GR-

And here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

typedef unsigned __int8 uint8;

int main()
{
    class BaseFoo
    {
    public:
        virtual ~BaseFoo() = default;

        virtual void doIt(const std::string& x, const uint8 y) = 0;
    }; // class BaseFoo

    class Foo : public BaseFoo
    {
        void doIt(const std::string& x, const uint8 y) override
        {
            std::cout << x << y;
        }
    }; // class Foo

    class Executer
    {
    public:
        void doIt(BaseFoo* f)
        {
            f->doIt("hello", 0);
            f->doIt("world", 1);
        }
    }; // class Executer

    Executer exec;
    BaseFoo* f = new Foo();
    exec.doIt(f);
    delete f;

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit 3:**

The point goes for Leon, if I move the classes out from the main function, the warning disappears. However I'm not sure why I'm wrong if I define those classes inside the main function. So the following code compiles without any warning:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

typedef unsigned __int8 uint8;

class BaseFoo
{
public:
    virtual ~BaseFoo() = default;

    virtual void doIt(const std::string& x, const uint8 y) = 0;
}; // class BaseFoo

class Foo : public BaseFoo
{
    void doIt(const std::string& x, const uint8 y) override
    {
        std::cout << x << y;
    }
}; // class Foo

class Executer
{
public:
    void doIt(BaseFoo* f)
    {
        f->doIt("hello", 0);
        f->doIt("world", 1);
    }
}; // class Executer

int main()
{
    Executer exec;
    BaseFoo* f = new Foo();
    exec.doIt(f);
    delete f;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can't repro in VS2013 with the obvious change of putting the bit at the end inside `main`. Please post a complete compilable example and say which version of VS you're using.

Comment: With this code I only get "unreferenced formal parameter" for x and y at /W4, which I expect (MSVC 2013)

Comment: Same here, no repro in vs2015

Comment: Okay, I'm creating a test project, I will upload it (to dropbox I guess). Anyway, I'm using VS2013 as well.

Comment: Is there more text to the warning? You don't use `x` and `y` So this may be the cause of the error.

Comment: No.  Not a test project.  A simple .cpp file with all the declarations and everything in one file (including main) -then [edit] your question to show that.

Comment: Which Visual Studio and is this the exact code? It's ok in VS2015

Comment: @Hayt: nope, no more text, so it's not referring to the x and y variables.

Comment: @doctorlove: VS2013 Update 3

Comment: Do you compile with c++11 ?

Comment: @Tezirg: Haven't done any special setup for c++11 but I'm using c++11 functionality which works, so I guess: yes, I do.

Comment: I still don't get a single warning with the code you posted.

Comment: I can confirm this with everything in `main`. Looks like a bug to me because `BaseFoo::doIt` *is* actually used in `Executer::doIt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you declare your classes as local to a function, leaving no chance for anyone to inherit from `BaseFoo` and override its `doIt()` method.

Comment: The local to the function classes are all part of the `MCVE` request.

Comment: Actually this was the problem. If I move out these classes from the main function, the warning disappears. However I think this should work anyway, since the Foo inherits from the BaseFoo. Is this supposed to be a bug?

Comment: @csisy I don't think that you should label the warning as a bug. An abstract class doesn't make much sense if it is local. Abstract classes are introduced with the purpose to encourage subclassing them, which is impossible if they are hidden inside a function.

Comment: That doesn't mean it's not a bug. It's just a kind of bug that can only be triggered by code that is hardly useful.

Comment: I still think it's not against the standard. What if I want a local `BaseFoo` base class and inherit multiple `Foo`s from it? Eg. for testing purposes. It's okay, I can move those classes out from the function, but I think this should work as well. Anyway, you've solved the problem, got that tick. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class BaseFoo
{
public:
    virtual ~BaseFoo() = default;

    // As a pure-virtual is intrinsically a "do-nothing"
    // the name of the parameters doesn't matter for the compiler
    virtual void doIt(const std::string& /* x */, const uint8 /* y */) = 0;
}; // class BaseFoo

class Foo : public BaseFoo
{
    // Other compilers are even Nazi-er than VS and emit a whinge... 
    // errr, pardon my mouth, I meant to say...
    // a warning for any unused parameter ('g++ -Wall', I'm looking at you)        
    // The same works too for keeping them happy and silent.
    void doIt(const std::string& /* x */, const uint8 /* y */) override
    {
    }
}; // class Foo
```

Comment: If I keep these classes inside the main function (as in my OP), the problem persists, the warning is about the doIt function itself, not its parameters unfortunately. But thanks for the tip!

Comment: " the warning is about the doIt function itself, not its parameters unfortunately." Ah, Ok. Good to know.